# How to rename SQl Scripts on MySQL Model?

Tags: mysql-workbench

i'm pretty new on MySQL Workbench and i really dont know how to rename an SQL Script on the MySQL Modeling panel...

[image]

I'm feeling a bit silly about!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just click on the selected script one more time with a minimal delay (NOT double-click!). You'll be able to edit the name.

Comment: That's unreasonable! Thanks for the tip!